# No se muestra weblogic 12 en netbeans 11 como opcion en add server

Tags: web, netbeans, maven, weblogic

buenos días comunidad.
tengo instalado el servidor weblogic 12  y tengo el IDE netbeans 11. Descargue el instalador Binaries https://archive.apache.org/dist/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans-java/incubating-9.0/incubating-netbeans-java-9.0-bin.zip 
y ya tengo instalado el weblogic 12 c.

El detalle es que cuando creo un proyecto en netbeans y despues me voy a la sección server para agregar mi weblogic no me aparece en las la lista de servers disponibles

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

revise la información de la pagina de weblogic https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/wls_12c_netbeans_install/wls_12c_netbeans_install.html y solo indica que debe aparecer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me pueden indicar que necesito?  es un plugin, es la versión o que diablos porque no encuentro información en ingles ni español, de antemano gracias

Comment: Por lo que he visto en el stackoverflow en ingles, no lo soporta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938248/i-can-not-add-the-weblogic-server-in-netbeans-v11 Yo lo he intentado también y es cierto que no aparece en el desplegable y con netbeans 8.2 si me aparece

Comment: Tiene sentido que sea así. Debe haber un montón de problemas de licenciamiento (NetBeans cambió de manos y está en Apache, Weblogic ahora está en las tripas de Oracle). El plugin no debe haber sido actualizado

Comment: No se puede guru, solo con versiones previas de netbeans.

Comment: gracias, un poco tarde, pero gracias.